# Vertically align items inside row flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a list that I want the items to appear aligned inside a `listView`. But my logic don't work well as the items don't align well since they have different width.

[image: Expected result here]

[image: current result]

**Code**

```
  ListView.builder(
                         physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                         shrinkWrap: true,
                         itemCount: mainBloc.walletHistory!=null?
                         mainBloc.walletHistory.length:0,
                         itemBuilder: (context, index){
                           return Container(
                             margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 14),
                             child:  Row(
                               children: [
                                 Text(
                                   mainBloc.walletHistory[index].createdAt
                                       .substring(2,7),
                                   textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: transactionTextColor,
                                       fontSize: 18,
                                       fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                 ),
                                 Spacer(),
                                 Text(
                                   mainBloc.walletHistory[index].action??"None",
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: HexColor("#6B7377"),
                                       fontSize: 18,
                                       fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                 ),
                                 Spacer(),
                                 Container(
                                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                   child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                     'assets/images/blacknaira.svg',
                                     color: primaryColor,
                                   ),
                                 ),
                                 Text(
                                   '${mainBloc.walletHistory[index]
                                       .transactionAmount
                                       .toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                                   textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: primaryColor,
                                       fontSize: 18,
                                       fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                 ),
                                 Spacer(),
                               ],
                             ),
                           );
                         },
                       ),
```

I tried using the space because I wanted all the items to have equal width but now I have an issue because they are not aligned vertically inside the row which makes it look scattered as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get items in a row to align by column is by creating fixed widths for items in a row and expand the item in the row that holds the most content.

I refactored the `ListView.builder` to show an example a bit better.

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: mainBloc.walletHistory!=null?
  mainBloc.walletHistory.length:0,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return TransactionRow(history: mainBloc.walletHistory[index]);
  },
);
```

And I created a `TransactionRow` widget that passes the data it needs to complete it.

```
class TransactionRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final double dateRowWidth = 75.0; // {double} for date width
  final double amountRowWidth = 150.0; // {double} for amount width
  final history; // Might want to typecast this

  const TransactionRow({Key? key, this.history}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 14.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: dateRowWidth,
            child: Text(
              history.createdAt.substring(2, 7),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: transactionTextColor,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              history.action ?? "None",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: HexColor("#6B7377"),
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: amountRowWidth,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/blacknaira.svg',
                    color: primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${history.transactionAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: primaryColor,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontFamily: 'Inter',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```